# using ASP Identity Users in a project with a lot of active users

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm changing a completed website project structure from web form to MVC. Having more than 100 users and the current login system is with browser cookies.
My problem is with the user passwords, which are saved using one way hashing system in SQL store procedure:

```
HashBytes('SHA1', CONVERT(nvarchar(4000),@password))
```

Is there any possible way to change the old system and use ASP Identity Users in the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Identity used salted hashed passwords rather then just hashed passwords. You could probably do a custom usermanager to use your existing logic but I wouldn’t recommend it. You are probably better off requiring that users on login reset their passwords with a notice about improving security.